# Unity3d: My knockback script is not working

Tags: c#

My code doesn't work. When I collide with an object nothings really happening, I made sure that my objects box collider is checked to isTrigger, and I also increase the explosionStrength. What am I doing wrong could anyone help?

```
public class Knockback : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float explosionStrength = 10.0f;

    void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D target_)
    {
        Vector3 forceVec = -target_.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.normalized * explosionStrength;
        target_.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(forceVec,ForceMode2D.Force);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you in 3d or 2d?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing unity3d code and unity 2d code if you are in unity 3d then your code may need to be changed to this...

```
public class Knockback : MonoBehaviour {
    public float explosionStrength = 10.0f;

    void OnTriggerEnter (Collider target_){
    Vector3 forceVec = -target_.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().velocity.normalized * explosionStrength;
        target_.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(forceVec,ForceMode.Force);
    }
}
```

If you are in 2d your code may need to be changed to this

```
    public class Knockback : MonoBehaviour {
    public float explosionStrength = 10.0f;
    public GameObject player;
    void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D target_){
         Vector2 forceVec = new Vector2 (-target_.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.normalized.x * explosionStrength, -target_.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.normalized.y * explosionStrength);
    target_.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(forceVec,ForceMode2D.Force);
}

}
```

I have tested the 2d code and it has worked fine. Just make sure you put it on the object to explode not the player.